# 'TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable' How do I make a function iterable?

Tags: python, function, seaborn, typeerror, iterable

I am trying to generate 6 violin suboplots using seaborn in python. I am running into an error stating that 'Argument of type function is not iterable'. I want to know if I am missing something from my code or if something is missing from my seaborn import. When I enter 'print(dir(sns.violinplot))' in the console, **iter** is not present and I wonder if that is causing the error? Thanks in advance! Here is the code and the error message I get.

````
hue = "Mutation"
col = "Subregion"
kind = "violin"
data = M1
title_name = "M1"



VAR = M1.columns[7:]
YL = ["Area (mm^2)","DAPI Cell Count","SST Cell Count","DAPI Cell Density (DAPI/mm^2)","SST Cell Density (SST/mm^2)","SST Cell Density (% SST/DAPI cells)"]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2,figsize = (8,8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
axs = axs.reshape(-1)
for k in range(len(VAR)):
    sns.violinplot(x = x in sns.violinplot, y = VAR[k], hue = hue, col = None, kind = kind, data = M1,ax=axs[k])
    axs[k].set_ylabel(YL[k],fontsize=8)
    axs[k].legend_.remove()
axs[-1].legend(loc='upper right', ncol=1,bbox_to_anchor=(1.5,1.5))
plt.show()```

```File "<ipython-input-70-0506b9c647bf>", line 41, in <module>
    sns.violinplot(x = x in sns.violinplot, y = VAR[k], hue = hue, col = None, kind = kind, data = M1,ax=axs[k])

TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable```
````

Comment: What are you trying to do with this statement: `x = x in sns.violinplot`?

Comment: `x = x in sns.violinplot` is the bit causing the error, as it tries to search for `x` through `sns.violinplot` which is a function.  Not quite sure what you were trying to do, so I don't know what you should change it to

Answer (score 1):

You don't iterate over a function; you might use it to produce an iterable, but the function itself is not an iterable object.  (It is technically possible to construct an object in Python that is both iterable and callable, but... no.  That's not the road to solving this problem.)

I'm pretty sure this statement makes no sense and indicates that you might be overcomplicating this entire thing due to not understanding how the function works:

```
sns.violinplot(x = x in sns.violinplot ...
```

From looking at the documentation (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)  it looks like maybe instead of that entire loop you just want:

```
axs = sns.violinplot(y=VAR)
```

or something close to that?